# How to change background color of table row if value >=1000?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to change background color of some rows in table, when input of row is >=1000 and I click the button. I'm doing it with inputs in table and submit button. In php I'm making variable int from input and in JS checking if it is <=1000 and changing background color. But it is just for a moment, after that page is refreshing, shouldn't be. Here's my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>

<thead>

      <tr>

         <th>first</th> <th>second</th> <th>third</th>

      </tr>

   </thead>

   <tbody>

      <tr id="1">

         <td>1</td> <td><input type="text"  name="value11" /></td><td><input type="text"  name="value12" /></td>

</tr>
     <tr id="2">

         <td>2</td> <td><input type="text"  name="value21" /></td><td><input type="text"  name="value22" /></td>

</tr>

   </tbody>
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['green'])){
            $value21 = (int)trim($_POST['value11']);

            $value21 = (int)trim($_POST['value21']);}
?>   
</table>
 <button type="submit" name="green" onclick="makeGreen()">button</button> 
</form>



 <script> 
function makeGreen() { 
    var val1 = "<?php echo json_encode($value11) ?>";
var val2 = "<?php echo json_encode($value21) ?>";
    if(val1 >= 1000)
            document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "green";


if(val2 >= 1000)
            document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "green";

        } 
    </script>
```

Can You tell me what is wrong? Why it is not working?

Comment: The `<button>` submits the form, which in this case is a reload of the page.

Comment: Use  `<button type="button" ` instead to avoid submit, or a different button, or a javascript programmatically form submit

Comment: @FelippeDuarte `type="button"` Then `$_POST['green']` won't be set

Answer (score 0):

When the button is hit, you're actually calling the function makeGreen(), then your form is submitted.

If you only want to make the background row green by hitting the button, you should replace the submit type by a button one, try this :

```
<button type="button" name="green" onclick="makeGreen()">button</button>
```